# .equals function returns false when used to compare 2 livedata objects

Tags: kotlin

I have 2 mutable live data objects

```
 val networkResponse = MutableLiveData<String>()
 val initialResponse = MutableLiveData<String>()
```

In my initial function I give them the the same values from the exact same variable:

```
fun initialResponser() = viewModelScope.launch {
        val valueVariable = try {
            db.collection("room1").get().await().size().toString()
        } catch(e: Exception) {
            Log.d("TAG", "Error getting documents: ", e)
            return@launch
        }
        initialResponse.value=(valueVariable)
        networkResponse.value =(valueVariable)
    }
```

In the second, I do the exact same operation, without any changes from the database or any other side:

```
   fun check() = viewModelScope.launch {
        val valueVariable = try {
            db.collection("room1").get().await().size().toString()
        } catch(e: Exception) {
            Log.d("TAG", "Error getting documents: ", e)
            return@launch
        }
        networkResponse.value = (valueVariable)
        if (initialResponse.toString().equals(valueVariable)){
            Log.d(TAG,"Equals")
        }else{
            Log.d(TAG,"Not Equal")
            Log.d(TAG, initialResponse.toString().equals(valueVariable).toString())
            Log.d(TAG,"Initial Value: ${initialResponse.value}")
            Log.d(TAG,"New Value: ${networkResponse.value}")
        }
    }
```

The result for `check()` in the Log is as follows:

```
D/TAG: Not Equal
D/TAG: false
D/TAG: 10
D/TAG: 10
```

When both the values are same where an I going wrong?

Comment: BTW, you don't need to call `equals()` explicitly; in Kotlin, you can just use `==` as that will call `equals()` for reference types (if not null).

Answer (score 0):

The values contained within LiveData objects can be accessed using `liveData.value`, so if you want to compare their values you have to write

```
initialResponse.value.equals(valueVariable.value)
```

In your code when you write `initialResponse.toString` this essentially returns something like `androidx.lifecycle.MutableLiveData@aaa84ba` and not the value 10 which you seem to expect